# Visual composer won't save?

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I dont know whats wrong with my site.
Since yesterday, I havnt been able to save changes in my editor visual composer. And Its only with the startpage. The others pages are fine.
And also, the startpage is not loading in visual composer at first, I need to make a hard reload in order to make it work (ctrl f5) Why is that? Does that have to do with not beeing able to save!?
Also, in responsive view, the headings are changing to default all the time, and the margins are messed up.

Help! Ive tried to deactivate some plugins to see if theres any conflict there, but havnt found anything.
What else can I do!? Also tried to make contact with visual composer support without any luck.

My site is [www.springertoken.se](http://www.springertoken.se)

best regards,
Lisa, sweden.

Comment: Can you please check if the startpage is having different page template than other pages? Also, you can enable debugging in WordPress to track the issue. Read this for debugging: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you for reypling!
I dont have a specific template for startpage, and now I noticed that another page also wont load in visual composer when Im entering edit mod.e I have checked the debuging link you recomend me to check out, but it says that its for working local, and this site is live. So I dont really know what to do :( 

best regards 
Lisa

Comment: Do you see any error in browser console while editing the pages?

Comment: I can see that its something about JQuery.

Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function
    at Object.init (post.php:2376)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (post.php:2386)
    at e (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=underscore,utils,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,moxiejs,plupload,wp-codemirror&ver=5.8.1:6)
    at t (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=underscore,utils,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,moxiejs,plupload,wp-codemirror&ver=5.8.1:6)

Comment: and


load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=underscore,utils,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,moxiejs,plupload,wp-codemirror&ver=5.8.1:6 jQuery.Deferred exception: jQuery(...).live is not a function TypeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function
    at Object.init (https://springertoken.se/wp-admin/post.php?post=8245&action=edit&vcv-action=frontend&vcv-source-id=8245:2376:56)

Comment: at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://springertoken.se/wp-admin/post.php?post=8245&action=edit&vcv-action=frontend&vcv-source-id=8245:2386:34)
    at e (https://springertoken.se/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,utils,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,moxiejs,plupload,wp-codemirror&ver=5.8.1:6:30038)
    at t (https://springertoken.se/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,utils,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,moxiejs,plupload,wp-codemirror&ver=5.8.1:6:30340) undefined

I havnt touched Jquery. Why Is this telling me that its a conflict with it?

Comment: It seems there is a plugin conflict. Can you please deactivate plugin one by one and check it this resolves the issue. However, take backup of database and files before proceed.

Comment: I had a very similar issue, but only the CSS was not saved. It turned out, that I had to edit the CSS on the original (english) version of the page. The main pages are independently translated and saved, but maybe the multilanguage modul (WPML) somehow confuses something.